# Force Items to Route to Drop Off Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've been learning SharePoint for my organization so we can move away from local storage of documents to 'cloud-based' storage within SharePoint.  Not to mention, there are a bunch of other good reasons to move.

In any case, is there a way to force all uploaded documents to route to the drop-off library, so that the content organizer rules can route them to their final destination?  I made it so the 'upload a document' button uploads directly to the drop-off library, but I am still able to drag and drop items directly to the documents library.  This is the problem- **I don't want people to be able to upload items to anywhere except the drop-off library.**

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds for your request:

1. Create retention policy in site settings->content type policy templates to move the document to another location, and apply this retention policy to content type in library settings->information management policy.
2. Create custom permission level for the document libraries. Create a permission level which untick “Add items” permission in site settings->site permissions.

Comment: Isn't a retention policy for items older than a certain age?  Also, for the permissions, that would stop users from uploading to the document center altogether, rather than moving them to the drop-off library, correct?

Comment: I did find the option to untick 'add items' but that applies to the whole site.  Members of that group cannot upload anything anywhere.